# Google maps javascript multiple methods error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am attempting to run the code below but am getting multiple methods error which I am unsure how to address. An example of such an error is Object # has no method 'getBounds' . I have registered from an API key which I have not included in the code below.

**Code**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            margin-top: 500px;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key={API_KEY}&sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
    google.load("maps","2.x"); 
    google.load("jquery","1.5.2");
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map')); 
      var burnsvilleMN = new GLatLng(44.797916,-93.278046); 
      map.setCenter(burnsvilleMN, 8); 
    });

    // setup 10 random points
    var bounds = map.getBounds(); 
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest(); 
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(); 
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng(); 
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat(); 
    var markers = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i<10; i++) { 
      var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()); 
      marker = new GMarker(point); 
      map.addOverlay(marker); 
      markers[i] = marker; 
    }

    $.each(markers, function(i, marker){
          // var marker = marker
          setInterval(function(){displayPoint(marker, i);}, 5000 + (i * 5000));
          });

          $('#map-info').appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));

    function displayPoint(marker, index){
        var x = marker.getLatLng();
        $('#map-info').hide();
        var moveEnd = GEvent.addListener(map, 'moveend', function(){
          var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(x);
          GEvent.removeListener(moveEnd);
        });
        map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
          }

    </script>

</html>
```

**Updated Code**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            margin-top: 500px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key={API_KEY}&sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
    google.load("maps","2.x"); 
    google.load("jquery","1.5.2");
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map')); 
      var burnsvilleMN = new GLatLng(44.797916,-93.278046); 
      map.setCenter(burnsvilleMN, 8); 

      // setup 10 random points
    var bounds = map.getBounds(); 
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest(); 
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(); 
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng(); 
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat(); 
    var markers = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i<10; i++) { 
      var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()); 
      marker = new GMarker(point); 
      map.addOverlay(marker); 
      markers[i] = marker; 
    }

    $.each(markers, function(i, marker){
          // var marker = marker
          setInterval(function(){displayPoint(marker, i);}, 5000 + (i * 5000));
          });

          $('#map-info').appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));

    function displayPoint(marker, index){
        var x = marker.getLatLng();
        $('#map-info').hide();
        var moveEnd = GEvent.addListener(map, 'moveend', function(){
          var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(x);
          GEvent.removeListener(moveEnd);
        });
        map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
          }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @stevether - Have added them in. Didn't think their absence would affect the code. Does it? Sorry am new to jQuery and Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$(document).ready()` function runs when the DOM is ready. However the other code runs as it is encountered — before the DOM is ready.

This means that the browser attempts to do `map.getBounds()` *before* `map` has been set up.

The solution is to do all the map operations together.

---

Note too that the map must be given an explicit size. You need something like this:

```
    div#map {
        height: 500px;
        width:500px;
    }
```

and giving **every** div a `margin-top` will adversely affect the map by applying that margin to every map tile. This needs to go:

```
    div {  // applies to every div element
        margin-top: 500px;
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I amended the code however nothing appears apart from the Google logo and a link to the terms and conditions. Have posted the updated code in my post.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey `$('#map-info').appendTo()` needs an element called `map-info` and you don't appear to have one. That should have caused an error in the console.

Comment: No it did not. I did however include an additional `div` element just below `<div id="map"></div>` as such `<div id="map-info"></div>`. There is still no map.

Comment: Did you add the height and width that @AndrewLeach mentioned? It didn't get added to your edited code. If not, that is probably your problem. If you did, can you post a link to a site that demonstrates the problem so we can debug it?